# Lost Permission on Files using wrong chmod syntax Centos 5.5

Tags: permissions, chmod

I was trying to remove write permissions on an entire directory, and I used the incorrect command:

`chmod 644 -r sites/default`

I meant to type

`chmod -R 644 sites/default`

The result was this:

```
chmod: cannot access `644': No such file or directory
$ ls -als sites
total 24
4 drwxr-xr-x  5 user group 4096 Jan 11 10:54 .
4 drwxrwxr-x 14 user group 4096 Jan 11 10:11 ..
4 drwxr-xr-x  4 user group 4096 Jan  5 01:25 all
4 d-w-------  3 user group 4096 Jan 11 10:43 default
4 -rw-r--r--  1 user group 1849 Apr 15  2010 example.sites.php
```

I fixed the permissions on the default folder with 
    $ chmod 644 sites/default
But, the following ls shows a all the files with red backgrounds and question marks.  I can't access any files unless I am root.

```
$ ls -als sites/default
total 0
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? .
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? ..
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? default.settings.php
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? files
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? settings.php
```

When I log in as root, I can edit all of the files, and their permissions appear correctly.  I do not know how to undo the damage caused by using -r with chmod instead of -R.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Try to reproduce this on a folder in your system.  I did $ mkdir test $ cd test $ touch test $ cd .. $ chmod 644 -r test  And that successfully reproduced my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do this:

```
chmod 755 sites/default
```

The output you are seeing is because you don't
have execute permission on the directory:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar
$ touch foo/bar/a foo/bar/b foo/bar/c
$ ls -l foo
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 thedward thedward 4096 2011-01-11 10:28 bar
$ ls -l foo/bar
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 c
$ chmod 644 foo/bar
$ ls -l foo/bar
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? a
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? b
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? c
$ chmod 755 foo/bar
$ ls -l foo/bar
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 thedward thedward 0 2011-01-11 10:28 c
```

Comment: Thanks that was quite simple, and you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run that same command again with the proper permissions then apply your desired permissions to sites/default?

Comment: I've tried that.  When I log in as root, go to the directory default, and run chmod 644 on certain files to give the permissions I want.  It appears to work, but when I exit and go back into the normal user, the files still can't be accessed. ls shows ? ?--------- ? ? ? ?